# How to reload the View in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reload

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Grid
                    Grid.IsSharedSizeScope ="False"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <RadioButton
                            Name="RadioButton"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="16"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            IsChecked="False" />
                        <TextBlock
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource RRWFont}"
                            FontSize="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=TextBlock}"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource DarkGrey}"
                            Text="{Binding Path=Content.Name}"
                            TextAlignment="Left"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Image
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Width="auto"
                        Height="auto"
                        Source="{Binding Path=Content.File}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="RadioButton" Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="RadioButton" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

XAML (ListBox)

```
   <ListBox
        Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Background="{x:Null}"
        BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AnswersVariants}"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectAnswer, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectionMode="Single">

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Loaded="ListBoxWrapPanel_Loaded"
                    Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

C#

```
private void ListBoxWrapPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is WrapPanel panel))
        return;
    if (panel.Children.Count == 0)
        return;

    var max = (from FrameworkElement panelChild in panel.Children
            select panelChild.ActualWidth + panelChild.Margin.Left + panelChild.Margin.Right)
        .Concat(new double[] { 0 }).Max();
    panel.ItemWidth = max;
}
```

I have this ContentControl: (class names have been changed)

```
*XAML:*
ContentControl
            Content="{Binding CurrentContent}"
 I change the CurrentContent like this:

CurrentContent = new ContentOne();
CurrentContent = new ContentTwo();
```

INotifyPropertyChanged, etc. for MVVM is created and it all works
correctly.

There is such a problem. When one CurrentContent changes to another,
but of the same class, the View does not change, it only changes the
data.

Those.

```
CurrentContent = new ContentOne(); //1
---over time
CurrentContent = new ContentOne(); //2
```

In the second case, View remains the same.

This causes a problem, because in View there is a ListBox, ItemPanel
which represents WrapPanel. For all WP children, the heights and
widths are the same and are set during the initialization of the View
by finding the greatest widths and heights. When the ViewModel
changes, but View does not change, the following can happen:

View for *1: [image]

View for *2: [image]

You will not be able to recalculate altitudes and widths, because they
are considered when they are not already set for WrapPanel, and in the
case of * 2 they are already set.

P.S. In this case everything works correctly:

```
CurrentContent = new ContentOne();
---over time
CurrentContent = new ContentTwo();
---over time
CurrentContent = new ContentOne();
```

Comment: *"the heights and widths are the same and are set during the initialization of the View by finding the greatest widths and heights"* -- Your XAML is broken. Don't set widths and heights that way. Your code behind should have no code at all for layout, alignment, widths, etc. You can do all that stuff using WPF layout techniques such Grids, HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment, etc. so it will update automatically when it needs to. If you show us the XAML that has the problem, we can help you fix it so this will not be an issue.

Comment: If you're absolutely unable to write proper XAML, create a DataContextChanged event handler and call your layout code from there.

Comment: I need the children in WrapPanel to have the same width and height, so after downloading WP I do this:
    private void ListBoxWrapPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(sender is WrapPanel panel))
                return;
            if (panel.Children.Count == 0)
                return;
            var max = (from FrameworkElement panelChild in panel.Children
                    select panelChild.ActualWidth + panelChild.Margin.Left + panelChild.Margin.Right)
                .Concat(new double[] { 0 }).Max();
            panel.ItemWidth = max;
}

Comment: 1) Please don't post code in comments. As you can see it's unreadable. 2) I didn't ask about the details of your code. You're doing it wrong. The exact details don't matter at all. The code in your comment is bad and should not exist. Did you even read either of my comments?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not know that it would work out.
To solve this problem, I need to do something so that all WrapPanel children have the same size. I do not know how to do it, except by hand. Grid is not suitable, because I do not know in advance how many objects there will be.

Comment: Why should I try to help you if you refuse to read anything I tell you?

Comment: I do not know how to add code. I can not edit my question, tk. he is already too long

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking the edit link. You can add code by pasting it in. If the code comes out formatted wrong, you can select the code with the mouse and press Ctrl+K to indent it. This will cause it to be formatted correctly.

Comment: added code that causes a problem

Comment: Thanks. I see that `ListBoxWrapPanel_Loaded` does nothing. Can you show me the code that sets the widths you're having a problem with?

Comment: Did not add panel.ItemWidth = max; at the end of the function, when cut off from the rest of the unrelated code

Comment: Please post your actual code. You're asking for help, but you're fighting me every step of the way.

Comment: I'm sorry. There was an error while editing.

Comment: I found a solution.
Instead of WrapPanel, you need to use UniformGrid.
Thank you more that despite my inadequacy, you tried to help me! :-)

Comment: Excellent! In WPF, there's almost always a simple way to make the layout just do what you want, without any code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of WrapPanel, you need to use UniformGrid.